# Probability that hand contains Ace and King of at least one suit?

Tags: probability, statistics, card-games

Compute the probability that a hand of 13 cards (drawn
randomly from a standard deck of 52) contains both the ace and the
king from at least one suit.

I think I would use the inclusion exclusion principle here, but I'm not sure how to start. Would it be something like: P(Ace+King of suit 1) + P(Ace+King of suit 2) + P(Ace+King of suit 3) + P(Ace+King of suit 4) - ... so on.?

Comment: Do the ace and king have to be from the same suit, or can they be from different suits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

In my original answer, I ignored the condition that the ace and king are in the same suit. That is partly due to the awkward language, which technically can support my reading.  But there is no reason for the question to mention suits at all if the problem was about just having an ace and a king,

so I'm taking the suggestion by commenter AnkitSeth that the correct reading that we are looking for the probability that the hand has, for at least one suit, the ace and king of that suit.

---

Let $A$ be the set of all deals.

Let $A_i$ be the deals that contain the ace and king of suit $i,$ for $i=1,2,3,4.$

Then the inclusion-exclusion gives the probability:

$$\frac{\binom{4}{1}|A_1|-\binom{4}{2}|A_1\cap A_2|+\binom{4}{3}|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|-\binom{4}{4}|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4|}{|A|}\\=\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{50}{11}-\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{9}+\binom{4}{3}\binom{46}{7}-\binom{4}{4}\binom{44}{5}}{\binom{52}{13}}$$

---

**Original Answer**

This answer finds the probability that the hand has one ace and one king.
If $p$ is the probability that you get at least one ace and one king, consider $$1-p = p_{\lnot A}+p_{\lnot K}-p_{\lnot AK}$$ where $p_{\lnot A}$ is that probability that you didn't get any ace, $p_{\lnot K}$ is the probability that you got no king, and $p_{\lnot AK}$ is the probability that you got no ace and no king.

So $$p_{\lnot A} = p_{\lnot K}=\frac{\binom{48}{13}}{\binom{52}{13}}$$ and $$p_{\lnot AK}=\frac{\binom{44}{13}}{\binom{52}{13}}$$

So $$p = \frac{\binom{52}{13} - 2\binom{48}{13} + \binom{44}{13}}{\binom{52}{13}}$$

Comment: What rule did you use to set up the initial equation?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Your answer does not match with the given one in book. The answer in book is 0.2198

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about the same question? 0.2198 seems very low for $13$ cards. The expected number of aces you get is $1,$ and the expected number of kings is $1.$ @AnkitSeth

Comment: This is question 55, Chapter 2 from the book - A First course in probability (Sheldon Ross 8th ed). You can check here - http://www.julio.staff.ipb.ac.id/files/2015/02/Ross_8th_ed_English.pdf

Comment: The question is also not clear on whether the Ace and King are from same suit or different. I tried both ways, but none matches the answer.

Comment: It would help to have.a page number. @AnkitSeth

Comment: Page 54 in pdf, question 55 (a)

Comment: It clearly means an Ace and King of the same suit, or there would be no need to mention the suits. (Although the language is sloppy. It should say: The probability of the hand containing the ace and king of the same suit, for at least one suit.)  That is  a different question, although again best done with inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: You should get: $$\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{50}{11}-\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{9}+\binom{4}{3}\binom{46}{7}-\binom{4}{4}\binom{44}{5}}{\binom{52}{13}}$$ @AnkitSeth

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127871/discussion-between-ankit-seth-and-thomas-andrews).

Comment: Yes, the language is sloppy, but I have two questions. First - how is it a different question? Looks same to me. Second - The question is talking about a hand of 13 cards, so how did you get $\binom{50}{11}$, $\binom{48}{9}$ etc? I mean, what are the 4 events you took for inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: Heh, I think my answer was ignoring the suit part of the question. You are correct, this is the same question. There are $\binom{50}{11}$ hands with the $AK$ of hearts. Same for the $AK$ for each suit. we’ve overcounted the cases where we have both the ace and king in two suits. There are $\binom{48}{9}$ hands with the $AK$ of spades and hearts, and the same for any two suits. Etc.

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect the correct question. @AnkitSeth